# PHP: If number is divisble by 3, minus 1 (2, 5, 8, 11 etc)

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have a loop that creates divs with some content from a database. I have a variable `$current_count` which I'm starting at value '`0`' which is the first iteration of my loop.

I am using:

```
if ($current_count == 0 || $current_count % 3 == 0) { echo '<div class="parent">'; }
```

To create a parent div at the very top of the loop, then again on every iteration divisible by 3. It looks like this (with numbers representing iteration):

```
0 <div class="parent">
0    <div class="child"></div>
1    <div class="child"></div>
2    <div class="child"></div>
3 <div class="parent">
3    <div class="child"></div>
4    <div class="child"></div>
5    <div class="child"></div>
```

But the problem is I can't work out how to close those divs, as they would close on different iterations. For example, the parent opened on iteration `0` would need to be closed at the end of iteration `2`.

I need to basically say (pseudo-code):

```
IF $current_count is equal to (division of 3, minus 1) { etc }
```

I have tried:

```
if ($current_count % 3 == (0 - 1)) {}
if ($current_count % (3 == 0) - 1) {}
if ($current_count % 3 == 0 - 1) {}
```

But none of these are returning true. Does anyone know a way I can do this?

Cheers,
Lee.

UPDATE 1: Here's an example of the PHP code currently, to better explain what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$current_count = '0';
$ret = '';

        foreach ( $brands as $index => $brand ) : 

if ($current_count == 0 || $current_count % 3 == 0) {
                    $ret.= '<div class="parent">'; //Start parent
                }

                $ret.= '<div class="child"></div>'; //Child

if ($current_count % 3 == (0 - 1)) { // IF LINE 2, 5, 8, 11 etc, NOT WORKING
                            $ret.= '</div>'; // End the parent
                        }

            $current_count++;
        endforeach;
```

Comment: I think you need decremented value inside the if block. something like
if ($current_count % 3 == 0) { $current_count = $current_count -1; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
    for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
         if($i % 3 == 0 && $i > 0)// $i > 0 condition because. 0 % 3 is equal to 0 only.
              echo $i - 1;// will echo 2,5,8
              echo "</div>";// in your case.
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Niranjan N Raju - I need this to work within a loop, and I need it to work on iteration 2, 5, 8, 11 etc dynamically (all multiples of 3, minus 1). I don't need to echo those values, I need to see if the current iteration of the loop matches any of those values. Will your code work for that? Can you please explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: @LeeValentine check the answer, its inside a loop and will wor accordingly. I have echoed there just to show, it works. You can add what you what there.

Comment: @LeeValentine Did it helped you?? r still facing any issue??

Comment: I've got it working now, thank you. Because my code was already in a foreach loop, I didn't need to use the for(), but your code gave me an idea. Because I already had `$current_count` starting from 0 and counting by 1 every iteration, I simply created a second var: `$current_count2 = $current_count + 1;` (it turns out I actually needed plus one by the way, but same fix), then used `if ($current_count2 % 3 == 0) {
       $ret.= '</div>'; // End of parent on line 2, 5, 8 etc
      }`  Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome.. Glad It helped you:)

Answer (score 0):

if you do it like that it still divided by 3 and not solving the question.

it should be :

```
if( $key % 3 == 2 ){
   </div>
}
```